# Consequences of the vanishing of the line integral of a 1-form on every closed piecewise polygonal with lines parallel to the axes

Tags: integration, differential-forms, line-integrals

Let $A$ be a path-connected set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $w\in\Omega^1(A)$ be a differential form of degree 1
$$
\omega = a(x,y)dx+b(x,y)dy. 
$$
Let's assume that $\tilde \gamma$ is any piecewise $C^1$ curve made by a sequence of line segments such that in each segment, only one coordinate varies, i.e., segments are parallel to one or the other coordinate axis.

From the knowledge that
$\int_{\tilde \gamma} w=0$

for every closed polygonal  $\tilde \gamma$ of this kind, can we conclude that the integral over every $C^1$ curve $\gamma$ is zero and then that $w$ is exact?

Here are my thoughts. I am inclined to think that the result should hold because the local difference between the integral over a small segment of extrema $(x_1,y_1)$ and  $(x_2,y_2)$ and that over the two segments of extrema $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ is second order in $dx=x_2-x_1$ and $dy=y_2-y_1$. Therefore, if $\tilde \gamma_{2n}$ is a polygonal line as defined above, where the extrema of every pair of $2n$ segments coincide with the curve $\gamma$, in the limit of $n\rightarrow \infty$, I would expect
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\gamma_{2n}}w = \int_{\gamma} w.
$$
Is this reasoning correct? Is there a more direct way to prove or disprove it?

Comment: What about finding a homotopy between $\tilde \gamma$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: @FedericoT. If I have well understood your suggestion, the presence of a homotopy with increasing $n$ between the $\gamma_{2n}$ curves is enough to conclude that the limit I wrote in the question holds?

Comment: All closed curves in $\mathbb R^2$ are homotopically equivalent, and you can assume your homotopy to be piecewise $C^1$. So the integral over any rectangle coincides with the integral over any closed piecewise $C^1$ curve. As $C^1$ curves are in particular piecewise $C^1$ you conclude

Comment: I do not follow @FedericoT.'s argument; this seems to assume that $w$ has been shown to be closed. However, you can easily argue that (by contradiction) by applying Stokes's Theorem. Of course, once you argue the form is closed, then by the Poincaré Lemma ytou know that it is exact.